# How to check if permission was granted? [CODENAMEONE]

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way in cn1 to check if specific permission was granted by user?
I see Android has `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` .Is it possible to avoid writing native code?

Comment: On Codename One it's permission/API specific e.g. `Display.isContactsPermissionGranted()`. There's no generic option since permissions are different between OSs.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I see the contacts permission is the only one in `Display` class. Do you plan adding more permission types or it's too specific?

Comment: We have others but they're in other places. This works the other way around, you need to ask for something specific then we make plans of adding it if it's missing. Permissions aren't uniform between Android and iOS so abstracting this is non-trivial